# Como usar a "response" de uma XMLHTTPREQUEST no CakePHP (2.5)

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp-2, http-request

**CONCLUSÃO:** coloquei aqui em cima para ficar logo a vista, eu estava usando o onClick para buscar esta função, mas estava deixando a requisição(request) fora da função por isso não estava funcionando.

Eu tenho uma ação no controller Posts:

```
                 public function pega($id = null)
                 {                      

                 $posts = $this->Post->findById($id);

                  foreach($posts as $pok)
                  {
                            $foda = $pok['love'];
                  } 

                  $this->set('foda', $foda);

                  $this->set('_serialize', array('foda'));

                }
```

Em meu layout tento fazer um request para pegar os dados da função "pega" e colocar dentro de uma tag html:

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:81/cakephp/posts/pega/<?php echo $post['Post']['id'];?  >.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 

var out = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 function loap (){ 
 var arr = out[0];
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = arr;
}

}

}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**Acrescentado:**

Sendo que isso só deve ocorrer quando um botão for clicado:

```
 <button type="button" onClick="loap()"> Checa </button>
```

O script ficou assiim:

```
<script>

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:81/cakephp/posts/pega/
                  <?php echo $post['Post']['id'];?  >.json";

//Eu tenho que criar a variável url porque preciso passar um id através do link...    

x.open("GET", url, true);
x.send();

var response = null;

x.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
   response = JSON.parse(x.responseText); 

}

function loap(){
       document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = response[0];    
}

</script>
```

Comment: Eu faria da seguinte forma: `return $this->response->body(json_encode($meuArray))`

Comment: Eu tentei várias formas, inclusive parecidas com essas, mas como saber que o que saiu de minha ação virou xmlhttp.responseText lá do outro lado?

Comment: Como ter certeza e como resgatar o valor?

Comment: Dá um f12 no google chrome, clique na aba "network".  Escolhe a aba XHR e veja se vai aparecer alguma resposta na url que você está mandando a ação do ajax, depois de atualizar a página

Comment: Cara eu fui no Headers e tá como ok (200) o request.

Comment: Mas você deve olhar o `Preview` na abinha ao lado do URL que apareceu em Network! Lá mostra o `JSON`. Se estiver vazio, é porque não tem dados como resposta!

Comment: Eu olhei, no preview mostra o código html/css...

Comment: Mas você quer retornar JSON ou HTML nessa consulta via ajax? Se for HTML, aí você é outro caso!

Comment: Eu quero poder usar o resultado para exibir na página, por exemplo, dentro de uma tag html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou dar um pequeno exemplo de como eu costumava utilizar

Controller do Cakephp

```
class JsonController extends AppController
{


    public function teste()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $json = json_encode(array('nome' => 'StackOverflow'));

        $this->response->type('application/json');
        $this->response->body($json); // json retornado {"nome" : "StackOverflow"}          
    }


}
```

Javascript:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest
x.open('GET', 'json/teste', true)
x.send();

var response = null;

x.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (x.readyState == 4) {
   response = JSON.parse(x.responseText)
}
```

}

### Atualização

Baseando no seu código, posso imaginar que você quer o seguinte:

```
 public function pega($id = null)
 {                      

    $posts = $this->Post->findById($id);

    $this->response->type('application/json');

    return $this->response->body(json_encode($posts));

}
```

No HTML

```
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest
    x.open('GET', 'json/teste', true)
    x.send();

    var response = null;

   var divQuerQueroImprimirOsValores = document.getElementById('ondeVouImprimir')

    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (x.readyState == 4) {
       response = JSON.parse(x.responseText)

       for (key in response) {

           divQuerQueroImprimirOsValores.innerHTML += response[key]    

       }
    }
```

Comment: Não é $this->autoRender= false; ? É porque eu li sobre o uso do serialize para fazer isso, mas não consegui colocar em prática. Vou ver esse seu exmplo e já respondo.

Comment: Vou fazer uma pequena alteração nessa parte. É que, no meu caso, o meu controller é só pra `JSON`

Comment: O `autoRender` agora está dentro do método :) Assim, somente esse método não usará `view`

Comment: Por que você não usou "var" antes do x? Estou tentando com seu exemplo, mas não consegui.

Comment: Espera aí! Se você quer retornar HTML, vai dar erro! Se for JSON, deverá funcionar.

Comment: Eu quero mostrar o resultado dentro de uma tag html...

Comment: Fiz desse jeito, tentei mudando um monte de coisas e nada. Detalhe: isso só deve funcionar se um botão for clicado, então coloquei onClick no botão e fiz uma função, mas deu errado.

Comment: Já olhou no `console` pra ver se algum erro ocorre?

Comment: Olhei, não tem nada indicando erro.

Comment: Eu estou achando que não é erro de programação, mas alguma configuração errada.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda e atenção! Eu esta esquecendo de colocar o request como parte da função que eu chamo no onClick, por isso não funcionava.